# LMER model won't estimate random slopes or plot VIF

Tags: r, lme4

### Data and Libraries

Here are my libraries:

```
#### Libraries ####
library(lmerTest) # HLM functions
library(performance) # HLM performance
library(lattice) # plotting HLM
library(tidyverse) # dplyr/plot stuff
```

Here is my dput:

```
work <- structure(list(Mins_Work = c(435L, 350L, 145L, 135L, 15L, 60L, 
60L, 390L, 395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 580L, 175L, 545L, 230L, 435L, 
370L, 255L, 515L, 330L, 65L, 115L, 550L, 420L, 45L, 266L, 196L, 
198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 343L, 207L, 263L, 332L, 0L, 
0L, 259L, 417L, 282L, 685L, 517L, 111L, 64L, 466L, 499L, 460L, 
269L, 300L, 427L, 301L, 436L, 342L, 229L, 379L, 102L, 146L, NA, 
94L, 345L, 73L, 204L, 512L, 113L, 135L, 458L, 493L, 552L, 108L, 
335L, 395L, 508L, 546L, 396L, 159L, 325L, 747L, 650L, 377L, 461L, 
669L, 186L, 220L, 410L, 708L, 409L, 515L, 413L, 166L, 451L, 660L, 
177L, 192L, 191L, 461L, 637L, 297L, 601L, 586L, 270L, 479L, 0L, 
480L, 397L, 174L, 111L, 0L, 610L, 332L, 345L, 423L, 160L, 611L, 
0L, 345L, 550L, 324L, 427L, 505L, 632L, 560L, 230L, 495L, 235L, 
522L, 654L, 465L, 377L, 260L, 572L, 612L, 594L, 624L, 237L, 0L, 
38L, 409L, 634L, 292L, 706L, 399L, 568L, 0L, 694L, 298L, 616L, 
553L, 581L, 423L, 636L, 623L, 338L, 345L, 521L, 438L, 504L, 600L, 
616L, 656L, 285L, 474L, 688L, 278L, 383L, 535L, 363L, 470L, 457L, 
303L, 123L, 363L, 329L, 513L, 636L, 421L, 220L, 430L, 428L, 536L, 
156L, 615L, 429L, 103L, 332L, 250L, 281L, 248L, 435L, 589L, 515L, 
158L, 0L, 649L, 427L, 193L, 225L, 0L, 280L, 163L, 536L, 301L, 
406L, 230L, 519L, 0L, 303L, 472L, 392L, 326L, 368L, 405L, 515L, 
308L, 259L, 769L, 93L, 517L, 261L, 420L, 248L, 265L, 834L, 313L, 
131L, 298L, 134L, 385L, 648L, 529L, 487L, 533L, 641L, 429L, 339L, 
508L, 560L, 439L, 381L, 397L, 692L, 534L), Coffee_Cups = c(3L, 
0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 6L), Start_Work = c(1015L, 1000L, 945L, 1400L, 1500L, 
915L, 930L, 1000L, 940L, 840L, 730L, 1700L, 945L, 1040L, 955L, 
945L, 930L, 745L, 800L, 955L, 1030L, 1115L, 905L, 930L, 815L, 
830L, 950L, 1108L, 1430L, 955L, 1313L, 1125L, 1636L, 1126L, 1027L, 
1323L, 1003L, 918L, NA, NA, 950L, 913L, 1244L, 656L, 930L, 718L, 
1744L, 759L, 928L, 912L, 857L, 930L, 907L, 920L, 1029L, 1027L, 
1211L, 914L, 1226L, 1337L, 951L, 1900L, 1313L, 1118L, 800L, 700L, 
1544L, 1350L, 905L, 1025L, 0L, 942L, 930L, 1234L, 1222L, 925L, 
0L, 2018L, 945L, 500L, 447L, 0L, 818L, 604L, 632L, 1015L, 930L, 
748L, 732L, 900L, 739L, 848L, 957L, 930L, 1144L, 627L, 1200L, 
825L, 624L, 736L, 846L, 1119L, 933L, 937L, NA, 631L, 1319L, 931L, 
1019L, 2141L, 900L, 820L, 920L, 925L, 619L, 917L, NA, 1413L, 
1014L, 910L, 1300L, 947L, 0L, 825L, 956L, 926L, 1057L, 959L, 
1056L, 1243L, 1147L, 1541L, 945L, 800L, 806L, 1000L, 816L, NA, 
1619L, 806L, 745L, 540L, 710L, 800L, 446L, NA, 926L, 758L, 930L, 
812L, 718L, 0L, 750L, 619L, 1134L, 1206L, 221L, 816L, 726L, 924L, 
850L, 513L, 915L, 800L, 858L, 444L, 807L, 703L, 658L, 1004L, 
700L, 700L, 1015L, 1011L, 1028L, 910L, 822L, 843L, 1052L, 901L, 
700L, 1047L, 802L, 900L, 807L, 2209L, 0L, 930L, 1014L, 842L, 
312L, 824L, 938L, 930L, NA, 813L, 854L, 907L, 715L, NA, 1137L, 
1404L, 942L, 830L, 1152L, 900L, 1017L, NA, 1218L, 1017L, 642L, 
832L, 700L, 838L, 940L, 1300L, 829L, 950L, 848L, 818L, 650L, 
1001L, 900L, 813L, 830L, 746L, 828L, 828L, 751L, 853L, 419L, 
517L, 1221L, 800L, 808L, 747L, 1049L, 606L, 1005L, 958L, 843L, 
856L, 0L, 744L), Month_Name = c("September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "October", "October", "October", 
"October", "October", "October", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "November", "November", "November", 
"November", "November", "November", "December", "December", "December", 
"December", "December", "December", "December", "December", "December", 
"December", "December", "December", "December", "December", "December", 
"December", "December", "December", "December", "December", "December", 
"December", "December", "December", "December", "December", "December", 
"December", "December", "December", "December", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "February", "February", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "February", "February", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "February", "February", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "February", "February", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "March", "March", "March", 
"March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", 
"March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", 
"March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", 
"March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", "March", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "May", "May"), Day_Name = c("Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-244L))
```

### LMER Model

I have made a LMER model that tries to predict productivity (Mins_Work) based off factors like coffee consumption and when I start working, but with the random effect of each month and day removed (there may already be issues with this given the months have only 28-31 observations per cluster, but figured I'd give it a go anyway).

Here is the model itself:

```
#### Simple MLR ####
simple.model <- lm(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work,
                   data = work)
simple.summary <- summary(simple.model)
simple.summary

#### LMER ####
work.model <- lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work + (1|Month_Name) + (1|Day_Name),
                   data = work)
work.summary <- summary(work.model)
work.summary
```

So far I have not had any giant red flags other than the heteroscedascity (which was flagged). However, there are some coding issues I need to sort out still.

### Problem

Most of the `check_model` plots/functions seem to work fine. However, one does not. Here is the saved object, which gives me nice visualizations:

```
check <- check_model(work.model)
```

For example for `plot(check$OUTLIERS)`:

[image]

However, when I try to use `plot(check$VIF)`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed at retrieving data :( Please provide original model or data through the `data` argument
```

And when I just try to run it as `check$VIF`, I get this error that is unfortunately in Chinese:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Tolerance", value = numeric(0)) : 
  替换数据里有0行，但数据有2
```

By my best translation, it is saying I have zero rows, but there are two values? I'm wondering if anybody else has had this error. Additionally, and likely a more important problem, I can't seem to get the model to estimate random slopes with this model:

```
lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work
     + (0|Month_Name) + (0|Day_Name),
     data = work)
```

This just gives me the following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  在为't'函数选择方法时评估'x'参数出了错: 不可以在类别为“dgTMatrix”的对象里的@‘Dim’槽指定类别为“numeric”的对象；is(value, "integer")的值不是TRUE
```

Can't really figure out what this error means but I figure people familiar with `lmer` ought to know what a simple number change in the model makes. Thanks in advance for any help you provide!

### Edit

I have solved one of the problems, as the error in my random slopes model was purely because I made the mistake of not including a random slope variable. Piggybacking off the comments of somebody who posted here, the model was also not nested properly, so for simplicity's sake I just removed `Day_Name`.

```
#### Solution: Add Random Slope Variable
summary(lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work
     + (0+Coffee_Cups|Month_Name),
     data = work))
```

This gives the typical summary output you would expect:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work + (0 + Coffee_Cups | Month_Name)
   Data: work

REML criterion at convergence: 3010.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.03866 -0.69180  0.01809  0.70571  2.68953 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Month_Name Coffee_Cups    45.42   6.739 
 Residual               22941.00 151.463 
Number of obs: 234, groups:  Month_Name, 9

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 504.52983   37.99989 228.69030  13.277  < 2e-16 ***
Coffee_Cups  18.46198    4.89654  21.60097   3.770  0.00108 ** 
Start_Work   -0.21626    0.03222 229.49555  -6.711 1.49e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Cff_Cp
Coffee_Cups -0.515       
Start_Work  -0.861  0.163
```

However, I'm still not understanding what is going on with `check$VIF`. The best translation I can come up with is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Tolerance", value = numeric(0)) :
   There are 0 rows in the replaced data, but the data has 2 rows.
```

I tried removing all NA values in case that had an impact, but that didn't fix anything. If anybody has a solution as to why it is causing the error, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can't help with those error messages, but I think your model is mis-specified. You are fitting crossed random effects, but they should be nested because the way Day is  coded, Friday in March is being treated as the same as Friday in Feb, whereas they are presumably different days. That won't fix the error you are getting though.

Comment: So the code should be this then?: 
`lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work + (1+Day_Name|Month_Name), data = work)`

Comment: No, no. That would fit random slopes for day ! You want something like `Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work + (1|Month_Name/Day_Name)`. See here for details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814

Comment: Oh wow okay I had that totally wrong. Lemme check my understanding...so theoretically if you had reaction time data and you had multiple subjects repeatedly tested on stimuli, would the model then be: `RT ~ IV + (1|stimuli/subject)`?

Comment: No worries. It's hard to say without more information about what `stimuli` is.  From your comment it seems more like a fixed effect (something that you change in your study/experiment), than a random effect. Details of the study design and your research question(s)  will inform the appropriate model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this question and figured out some workarounds. For the issues related to VIF, one can just use the following code from the same `performance` package.

```
#### Save Collinearity Check With VIF Data and Plot ####
check.vif <- check_collinearity(work.model)
check.vif
plot(check.vif)
```

Printing `check.vif` gives an output that includes the VIF:

```
# Check for Multicollinearity

Low Correlation

        Term  VIF   VIF 95% CI Increased SE Tolerance Tolerance 95% CI
 Coffee_Cups 1.04 [1.00, 2.34]         1.02      0.96     [0.43, 1.00]
  Start_Work 1.04 [1.00, 2.34]         1.02      0.96     [0.43, 1.00]
```

Using the `plot(check.vif)` plots it directly:

[image]